# Magnetic field of finite solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

Well, that's probably a well known question here, and I have seen some sorts of answers to this problem. But, I tried to calculate the magnetic field inside the middle of finite solenoid with radius $ R $ and length $ L $ myself, without involving integration over the angles.
I'd like to hear some of your opinions, because I'm not sure that what I've done is correct.

First, I found the magnetic field of one ring in a distance $ x $ above its symmetry axis.

The result:

$$ B_{p}=\frac{\mu_{0}\cdot I\cdot R^{2}}{2\left(R^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

Now, let $n$ be the number of turns per length unit of the solenoid. then, for any point $ P $ in on the axis of symmetry of the solenoid, it follows that :

$$ dB_{p}=\frac{\mu_{0}\cdot I\cdot R^{2}}{2\left(R^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot ndx $$

And therefore, for the point $ P $ in the middle of the solenoid, it follows that:

$$ B_{p}=\frac{\mu_{0}\cdot I\cdot R^{2}\cdot n}{2}\intop_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}}\frac{dx}{\left(R^{2}+x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{\mu_{0}\cdot I\cdot R^{2}\cdot n}{2}\cdot[\frac{x}{R^{2}\cdot\sqrt{x^{2}+R^{2}}}]_{\frac{-L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} $$

So, we have:

$$ B_{p}=\frac{\mu_{0}\cdot I\cdot n\cdot L}{\sqrt{L^{2}+4R^{2}}} $$

Any corrections will be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.
(I need thirty characters.)